# Python - logging using formatter and getLogger

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to add a timestamp to my `Python` `logging` code.

I have the code:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M')
log = logging.getLogger('Test_Service')

log.info('    Hello World')
```

But the output only shows:

```
INFO:Test_Service:    Hello World
```

How can I get the formatter to work here so that I can include the timestamp?

Comment: Did you do anything with the logging module before the code you show here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something else is calling `basicConfig()` first, and so your call has no effect.

You should ensure that:

1. There is only one call to `basicConfig()` from your code, and that's in a `main()` or called from the `if __name__ == '__main__` clause before a call to a `main()`.
2. There are no calls in your code to convenience `logging` module-level functions such as `logging.debug()` - such calls call `basicConfig()` automatically. Replace any such calls with `logger.debug()` where `logger` is any `Logger` instance (the root logger is allowed - just don't call the module-level convenience functions).
3. If it still doesn't work, you are using third party code which calls `basicConfig()` (library code should *never* do this) and you will need to investigate further.

Comment: Python 3.8 has a new parameter: `force=True` to override any existing basicConfig settings. Useful for Lambda function logging.